# DataTables - fixed columns widths across pages

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have seen a lot of questions asking how to set explicit column widths in DataTables - this is not what I am after.

I am perfectly happy with DataTables auto width calculation.

What I need is this: when the table is multiple pages, I want the width of each column to stay the same on each page, or regardless of sorting.

Currently, when the table loads, the columns are appropriately sized for the content displayed on that page.  When the user sorts the table, however, the column widths jump all around to fit the new content.

How can I get it to pick an appropriate width for all content, and stick with it? Preferably with configuration settings within the DataTables instantiation...

thanks

Comment: Datatables should handle this automatically when setting `autoWidth` to true (which is the default). This should also work when pagination is enabled. I just set up a minimal zero configuration example and it works just fine. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29CsV/).

Answer (score 2):

One possible way:

- Show all rows on one page
- Let `DataTables` do the automatic width calculation
- Set the calculated widths as explicit column widths
- Set the page size to your default value

When you try this and have more questions, post the code you got so far.

Comment: Sounds feasible. I will try it out.  I am a bit surprised this isn't a built in option still.